# Android ViewPager Delete Current Page and move to next

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged, current-page

In ViewPager when the user clicks on the delete button, I am trying to delete the current page and move to next page.
When I try below code, It moves to next page but removes the last page. Kindly help me.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int IdxVal)
{
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(imageListAryVar.get(IdxVal))
            .fitCenter()
            .into(imageView);

    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    container.addView(linearLayout);

    return linearLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
{
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}

void delCurrentPageFnc()
{
    int delIdxVar = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

    if(imageListAryVar.size() > 1)
    {
        if (delIdxVar == imageListAryVar.size() - 1)
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(delIdxVar - 1);
        else
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(delIdxVar + 1);

        imageListAryVar.remove(delIdxVar);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else finish();
}
```

Comment: can you try if you remove your `if (delIdxVar == imageListAryVar.size() - 1)
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(delIdxVar - 1);
        else
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(delIdxVar + 1);` ?

Comment: if I remove that, page won't automatically move to next page

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); wont call instantiateItem();

Comment: Maybe you can try `viewpager.removeViewAt(int index)`.

Comment: viewpager.removeViewAt(int index) does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of tries, I got this resolved by adding getItemPosition and setting return POSITION_NONE;
If u dont add this notifyDataSetChanged(); method won't work.

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object)
{
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

void delCurrentPageFnc()
{
    int delIdxVar = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

    if(imageListAryVar.size() > 1)
    {
        imageListAryVar.remove(delIdxVar);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else finish();
}
```

this was unnecessary after setting getItemPosition, So removed

```
if (delIdxVar == imageListAryVar.size() - 1) 
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(delIdxVar - 1);
else 
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(delIdxVar + 1);
```